# ERROR in Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ERROR in multi

Tags: angular

I have downloaded angular project from GitHub and when I run my project I am getting exception **ERROR in Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss ./node_modules/font-awesome-scss/scss/font-awesome.scss ./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css ./src/scss/style.scss**

I think its angular versioning issue can someone help me how can I solve this issue?

### packages.json

```
{
  "name": "mega-able-v1.7.2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --progress --output-hashing=all --port=4600",
    "build": "increase-memory-limit && ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.2.0",
    "angular2-chartjs": "^0.4.1",
    "angular2-notifications": "^0.7.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "c3": "^0.4.21",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "css-animator": "^2.3.0",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "font-awesome-scss": "^1.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng-click-outside": "^3.2.0",
    "ng-select": "^1.0.0-rc.4",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^3.4.0",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ng2-ui-switch": "^1.0.2",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-bar-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-carousel": "^1.3.5",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.6.5",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^5.3.3",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.3.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "screenfull": "^3.3.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.13.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

### The output of: ng --version

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 10.0.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core         7.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.1.4
@schematics/angular          7.1.4
@schematics/update           0.11.4
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.6
```

Comment: Can you please post `angular.json` code ? I think there's some path issue in that.

Comment: please check i updated angular.json code

Comment: remove ../ from ../node_modules in styles section. Should start from `node_modules` directly.

Comment: Could be worth checking that `environment.ts` exists too.

Comment: @user3145373 I tried that way also but same error I am facing

Comment: make sure your node_modules section will have all the required files.

Comment: I will send my github link if want

Comment: I have node_modules in my project

Comment: send `github` url.

Comment: https://github.com/Ukmandal/Angular-Jobeyee

Comment: why app.module.ts is in root directory ?

Comment: does you `node_modules` have `/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss` file ? can you please check file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186393/discussion-between-krish-and-user3145373-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here're the issues:

1. wrong `styles.scss` path and name inside `angular-cli.json`

   **fix**:

   `"styles.scss"`
2. environment files missing.

   **fix**:

   create `environments` directory under `src` directory and create 2 files named `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` under newly created `environments`.

Inside both files add code:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false
};
```

That's it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue doing the following.

1. Removed `node_modules` folder
2. Removed the file `package-lock.json`
3. Run `npm install` to re-install package dependencies.